# Resolving enums on client

Tags: apollo-client

On server I can do this

```
// server
const resolvers = {
  AllowedColor: {
    RED: 1,
    GREEN: 2,
    BLUE: 3,
  }
};
```

I would like to do the same on the client since I work with integer values. I have tried using resolvers in `ApolloClient` but they are not called at all.

```
// client
const resolvers = {
  AllowedColor: {
    RED: 1,
    GREEN: 2,
    BLUE: 3,
  }
};
```